# Android, Soundpool Class - autopause problems while looping sound

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, soundpool

I am having trouble in my program using the soundpool class. I initiated the soundpool builder and loaded my sounds with no problems.  I want to be able to use multiple togglebuttons that turn on and off specific sounds.  I am able to turn on and off togglebuttons, but for example if i turn two or more togglebuttons on and than i pause one.....the rest will stop.  I dont want that, i want the other sounds to keep playing.  Here is my code.  Also if anybody can help me clean it up a bit that would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bT1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.firstToggle);
        bT2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.secondToggle);
        bT1.setOnClickListener(this);
        bT2.setOnClickListener(this);
        bT3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.thirdToggle);
        bT4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fourthToggle);
        bT3.setOnClickListener(this);
        bT4.setOnClickListener(this);
        bT5 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fifthToggle);
        bT6 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.sixToggle);
        bT5.setOnClickListener(this);
        bT6.setOnClickListener(this);
        bT7 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.seventhToggle);
        bT8 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.eighthToggle);
        bT7.setOnClickListener(this);
        bT8.setOnClickListener(this);

        initionalizeSoundpool();
    }

    private void initionalizeSoundpool() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .build();

            ourSounds = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(8)
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                    .build();
            soundFx = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.highhatandrims, 1);
            beatOne = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.technodrums, 1);
            soundFx2 = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.soothing, 1);
            beatTwo = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.thumpohyeahbeat, 1);
            soundFx3 = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.dreamyone, 1);
            beatThree = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.atredundantsynthesis, 1);
            soundFx4 = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.tawaka, 1);
            clap = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.cabessa, 1);
        } else {
            ourSounds = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1);
            soundFx = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.highhatandrims, 1);
            beatOne = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.technodrums, 1);
            soundFx2 = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.soothing, 1);
            beatTwo = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.thumpohyeahbeat, 1);
            soundFx3 = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.dreamyone, 1);
            beatThree = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.atredundantsynthesis, 1);
            soundFx4 = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.tawaka, 1);
            clap = ourSounds.load(this, R.raw.cabessa, 1);
        }

    }




public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.firstToggle:
                if(bT1.isChecked()) {
                    ourSounds.play(soundFx, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
                }
                else {
                    ourSounds.autoPause();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.secondToggle:
                if(bT2.isChecked()) {
                    ourSounds.play(beatOne, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
                }
                else {
                    ourSounds.autoPause();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.thirdToggle:
                if(bT3.isChecked()) {
                    ourSounds.play(soundFx2, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
                }
                else {
                    ourSounds.autoPause();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.fourthToggle:
                if(bT4.isChecked()) {
                    ourSounds.play(beatTwo, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
                }
                else {
                    ourSounds.autoPause();
                }
                break;
```

Comment: what is the length of a sound file?

Comment: they are short samples, maybe 5-10 seconds long.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `OnPause` method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();   

   ourSounds.release();
   ourSounds = null;
}
```

**Update:**

Instead of `ourSounds.autoPause();`   please try to use `ourSounds.pause(soundID);` for example:

```
case R.id.firstToggle:
            if(bT1.isChecked()) {
                ourSounds.play(soundFx, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
            }
            else {
                ourSounds.pause(soundFx);
            }
            break;
 ...
```

Comment: I tried putting those two lines of code in the else statement right below the autopause but it didnt work.  iI would push two or three buttons and all would play, but when i paused one the others would stop and it would kick me out of program.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: No i mean inside `OnPause` method, please check my updated answer

Comment: Im still a beginner so i'm having trouble understanding.  I dont have a onPause method or onResume.  If i create onPause do i need a onResume?  Where do i call the onPause, in my else statement? Do i need to pass a int to onPause?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: just copy past my answer inside your `activity`.. outside your `onClick ` or `onCreate`...

Comment: I pasted in activity just above my onCreate where i set my setOnClickListeners than i have my initionalize soundpool() and than my onclick(view) and thats my whole java program.  The programs runs and i can toggle on/off each button and the music will start and stop with no problem.  But when i have two or more toggle buttons on and i turn one off, they both go off like before.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I really thought you had it.  It made sense to pause and pass it the variable.  It did not work though, it just kept playing the sounds even when i clicked the toggle button off. If i clicked the same button on again it would play a double loop of the sample.